# One of the specified object stores was not found

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/create-card.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Card - Create Card</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-div-container">
        <div class="input-div-container">
            <div class="front-label-div-container">
                <label>Front Page</label>
            </div>
            <div class="front-page-input-div-container">
                <input type="text" class="front-page-input" id="front-page-input">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-div-container">
            <div class="back-label-div-container">
                <label>Back Page</label>
            </div>
            <div class="back-page-input-div-container">
                <input type="text" class="front-page-input" id="back-page-input">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button-div-container">
            <button class="button" id="button">Save</button>
        </div>
        <div class="other-cards">
            <a href="/cards">
                <button class="other-cards-button">Other Cards</button>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="../js/create-card.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
const frontArea = document.getElementById("front-page-input");
const backArea = document.getElementById("back-page-input");
const saveButton = document.getElementById("button");

localStorage.setItem("cardAmount", 0)

const indexedDB =
    window.indexedDB ||
    window.mozIndexedDB ||
    window.webkitIndexedDB ||
    window.msIndexedDB ||
    window.shimIndexedDB;
const request = indexedDB.open("Cards-Database", 1)

request.onerror = () => {
    alert("Problem happened in the database");
};

request.onupgradeneeded = () => {
    const database = request.result;
    const DbObjectStore = database.createObjectStore("card-values", { keyPath: id })

    DbObjectStore.createIndex("front-value", ["front"], { unique: false })
    DbObjectStore.createIndex("back-value", ["back"], { unique: false })
};

request.onsuccess = () => {
    const database = request.result;
    const transaction = database.transaction("card-values", "readwrite");
    const cardStore = transaction.objectStore("card-values");

    saveButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const frontValue = frontArea.value;
        const backValue = backArea.value;
        const cardAmount = localStorage.getItem("cardAmount") + 1;

        localStorage.removeItem("cardAmount");
        localStorage.setItem("cardAmount", cardAmount);
        cardStore.add({ id: cardAmount, front: frontValue, back: backValue});
    });
    alert("Card Created");
}
```

Purpose is save reminder cards for study. I get:

> error: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found.

Database:

[image: Database Look In Developer Tools]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code. Here are the solutions;

> Error 1

```
const cardAmount = localStorage.getItem("cardAmount") + 1;
```

Here, when getting the cardAmount variable from localstorage, you must convert this variable to an int value. Otherwise, there will be an output like this: "01", "011" ...

> Error 2

```
    const DbObjectStore = database.createObjectStore("card-values", { keyPath: id })
```

Here, you must give the id parameter as a string, that is, it should be in "id".

> Error 3

To take the input values and save them to the database, you start a transaction immediately after the database access is successful, but you wait this transaction until the user presses the button. IndexedDb does not support such an operation. That's why you should start the transaction while pressing the button. The problem will thus be solved.

**The resulting code after correcting all 3 errors;**

```
const frontArea = document.getElementById("front-page-input");
const backArea = document.getElementById("back-page-input");
const saveButton = document.getElementById("button");

localStorage.setItem("cardAmount", 0)

const indexedDB =
    window.indexedDB ||
    window.mozIndexedDB ||
    window.webkitIndexedDB ||
    window.msIndexedDB ||
    window.shimIndexedDB;
const request = indexedDB.open("Cards-Database", 1)

request.onerror = () => {
    alert("Problem happened in the database");
};

request.onupgradeneeded = () => {
    const database = request.result;
    const DbObjectStore = database.createObjectStore("card-values", { keyPath: "id" })

    DbObjectStore.createIndex("front-value", ["front"], { unique: false })
    DbObjectStore.createIndex("back-value", ["back"], { unique: false })
};

request.onsuccess = () => {
    const database = request.result;

    saveButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const frontValue = frontArea.value;
        const backValue = backArea.value;
        
        // Fix for localStorage: Convert cardAmount to int
        const cardAmount = Number(localStorage.getItem("cardAmount")) + 1;

        localStorage.removeItem("cardAmount");
        localStorage.setItem("cardAmount", cardAmount);
        
        // Move the transaction and objectStore creation here
        const transaction = database.transaction("card-values", "readwrite");
        const cardStore = transaction.objectStore("card-values");
        
        cardStore.add({ id: cardAmount, front: frontValue, back: backValue });

        transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
            alert("Card Add Successfully");
        };
    
        transaction.onerror = function(event) {
            alert("error when try add card");
        };
        
    });

    alert("Card Created");
}
```